# creating new maven managed git controled project using intellij

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea

I got an empty repository hosted externally. I now want to locally create a intellij/maven managed java project which is source controled by that origin.

I tried:

```
1>check out from source control
2>"would you like to create an IDEA proect for the sources you have checked out?" - YES
3>import from external model
4>configure stuff
5>select maven projects to import
```

and now I am stuck as the list is empty.

I also tried

```
1> setting up the maven project manually
2> initializing the git repository in root directory
3> adding origin
4> importing project into intellij
5> configuring the root directory, as suggested by intellij, for git
6> committing changes
7> selecting push (cvs -> git -> push) -> "no changes to push"
```

I do not understand that as the origin is still an empty repository.

Therefore how do I tell intellij to create/use a maven project in the folder which is version controlled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is how IDEA prompts you after checking out code. There are two similar messages:

1. "Would you like to create an IDEA project for the sources you have checked out? *or*
2. "You have checked out an IntelliJ IDEA project file: {path}/pom.xml Would you like to open it?

If the first one is shown (which it appears it was for you), then IDEA will create a project from the sources and ***not*** from the maven POM. In the event of the second one, it will create it from the pom and your IDEA project will be linked to the maven POM. Even so, I personally like to select No to the auto create dialog. The reason is that when selecting yes, it opens the project immediately. Doing the below runs through a couple of configuration dialogs and gives me a bit more flexibility in how I set things up.

In general, the following sequence works for either of the above:

1. Check out from source control
2. Select **No** to the "Do you want to create a project" dialog.
3. File > Import Project

   - not to be confused with *New* Project
4. In the file chooser dialog, select the root `pom.xml` POM in the check out location from step #1
5. Configure your maven project via the dialogs

**If your initial checkout does not have a POM,**  you need to do the following to create a maven linked IDEA project:

1. Check out from source control
2. Select **No** to the "Do you want to create a project" dialog.
3. File > New Project
4. In the *New Project* dialog:

   1. Select "Maven" in the "Java" section of the project types
   2. Set the "Project Name"
   3. Set the "Project Location" value to the root directory of the project you checked out.
   4. Click Next
   5. Set your maven coordinates for your new project
   6. Select an archetype if you do not want to create a standard Java JAR project
   7. Click Finish
5. Optionally, go to Project > Settings > [Project Settings] > Maven and tweak any configurations
6. Add the pom file to VCS via the context menu or the VCS menu
7. Edit your POM and start coding

Comment: this basically is my second try description. But how can I tell itellij to also push the commit file(changes) to the remove host when asked to do so?

Comment: When you do the commit, at the bottom of the commit dialog, the commit button has a drop down arrow next to it. Use that to select "Commit and Push" from the drop down options. You can also select that via the `Alt`+`P` shortcut. There is not a "Always push on commit" option available.

Comment: yes, that was the solution. You might want to add that to your already quite throughout description.