# Intellij IDEA - Cannot add framework support for Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have sbt 0.13.16 and Scala 2.10.6 running with Intellij 2018.2.1, working with those recommended sbt and Scala settings for Odersky's coursera course on Scala (I'm guessing their automated submission grader depended on old SBT?).

When creating new sbt + scala projects, I choose the above sbt and Scala versions, then after all the dependencies have downloaded, when I right-click New -> ... I see options for Java class but nothing for Scala.  I have the Scala plugin already there according to the plugin settings.

So I try to Add Framework Support after right-clicking on the project, I select Scala, but then everything is disabled except Cancel.

I looked through previous forums, found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338015/cannot-add-framework-support-in-intellij-14-ultimate) but that seemed relevant only for git projects.

Anyone else run into this issue?  Do I need to update to more recent Scala and SBT?  Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Please check https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1347-scala/versions for a compatibility table.

You can manage plugins in IntelliJ Preferences. Your versions seem to be too old to still be supported, already. It may help to upgrade IntelliJ and then go to preferences and get the latest Scala and SBT plugins.